# How to get a value of a cell in datagridview devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, cell, identify

I have a Datagridview which contains checkboxes in the first column, and text in the second.
When a Checkbox is clicked, the "CellValueChanging"-method is getting the index of the specific row. 
How do I get the matching string-text? the Column-index of the text is always the same (1)

Comment: how about telling the reason for the downvote? -.-

Comment: i did'nt voted down but you should show your code how you tried and what you did

Comment: that was no offense on you, I'm thankful for your information. But in this case I didn't see any necessity on adding code since it is not depending on that code

Comment: you can show atleast `ValueChanged` event

Comment: okay, that's a point. That was what I meant, with Feedback I can improve, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GetRow()` method to get row:

```
var row = TaskGridView.GetRow(1) as YourModel;
```

using ValueChangedEvent:

```
private void TaskGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowHandle < 0)
            return;

    var row = TaskGridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as YourModel;       
}
```

for speicific column you can do:

```
 private void TaskGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.RowHandle < 0)
                return;

        var row = TaskGridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as YourModel;

       if (e.Column.FieldName.Equals("YourFieldName", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
       {
           // do something here
       }       
  }
```